# Custom x-axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the data I obtained. On the x-axis I would like to have a range of numbers from 1000 to 2500 and on the y-axis, a data set read from a file starting from the beginning.

I have tried the suggestions I have found on the internet and this site as well, but in the end, I obtain the graph which starts from 1000. data point in the data set, which is not what i want.

```
import numpy as nump
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = nump.loadtxt(rmsd.dat)
plt.plot(data[1000:,1])
plt.xlabel(frames)
plt.ylabel(rmsd)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently drops the first 1000 elements of data and just plots the remaining ones. Additionally, it doesn't specify any range for the x-axis at all.
Try this line:

```py
plt.plot(range(1000,2501), data)
```

The [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) state that if only a single parameter is provided it is used as y (quote) ***using x as index array 0..N-1***:

> `plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1`

Comment: thank you! I am rather new to python. I understand now.

Comment: Glad I could help you! Would you mind accepting my answer?